# inkbird ITC-708t 1850w max output pid temp controller running 2000w 120v heating element

Tags: voltage, heat, pid-controller

okay guys forgive me I'm just a dumb electrician/carpenter with a dream. I have caught the bug real bad in regards to home distillin. specifically still building. here is the deal, I didn't think in a million years the heating element in my kettle was over 12 amps but surprise its 16 something. i bought a ready made pid controller thinking i could plug and play until i noticed it was a 2000 watt element. So now i have to step down the voltage so i dont fry the inkbird. later i will build an inkbird 100vh with 25A ssr but for now i have got to do a flow test of my flagship still. can i just get a halogen dimmer to get me through the test? i was going to put the 20A dimmer switch in line with an amp meter and regulate it down to below 15A a little. i want to build a small still around the inkbird ITC-608t and dont want to hurt it. What say you engineers? will it work? there is a jar of awesome in it for anyone who helps!

Comment: Dimmer switches don't actually reduce the current.  They switch it on and off rapidly.  That's good enough to dim lamps or reduce the heat from a heater, but may not help your controller.

Comment: so is a dimmer a PWM? are there different types of dimmers? or a dimmer that  is special some how? should i just put together a bunch of resistors in series?

Comment: AC dimmers aren't usually PWM.  Instead, they chop a portion out of each half-cycle of the AC sinewave.  Leading edge dimmers chop off the start of the waveform, trailing edge dimmers chop off the end.